# Recode Dates with else statement being existing column value

Tags: r

I have a dataset and am trying to recode a date column.  The date column has 1900-01-01.  I want to change this to missing. Otherwise, I want it to contain the original date.

in SAS I would just do something like:

if date = '1900-01-01' then cleandate = ""; else cleandate = date.

Sample Data:

```
df <-data.frame(
id = c(1,2,3),
date = as.Date(c("1900-01-01", "1984-01-01", "1900-01-01")
))
```

desired outcome:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA (or however R assigns missing data so it won't be included in calculations) |
| 2 | 1984-01-01 |
| 3 | NA (or however R assigns missing data so it won't be included in calculations) |

Answer (score 0):

In R, take a copy of the existing date column, and then replace the values. Just be sure you specify the date in the YYYY-MM-DD default format.

```
df$cleandate <- df$date
df$cleandate[df$cleandate == '1900-01-01'] <- NA
df
#  id       date  cleandate
#1  1 1900-01-01       <NA>
#2  2 1984-01-01 1984-01-01
#3  3 1900-01-01       <NA>
```

Which can also be accomplished in one step using `replace`:

```
df$cleandate <- replace(df$date, df$date == '1900-01-01', NA)
df
#  id       date  cleandate
#1  1 1900-01-01       <NA>
#2  2 1984-01-01 1984-01-01
#3  3 1900-01-01       <NA>
```

You could of course skip the copy and just overwrite the values in `date` if that is preferred too:

```
df$date[df$date == '1900-01-01'] <- NA
df
#  id       date
#1  1       <NA>
#2  2 1984-01-01
#3  3       <NA>
```

Comment: thank you!  Just what I was looking for, and I can use that logic for other recodes.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a copy of `df`, `df2`, so that we can preserve the input and then use the `is.na<-` replacement function.  This places NA's onto the LHS where TRUE values are on the RHS.

```
df2 <- df
is.na(df2$date) <- df2$date == "1900-01-01"
```

**1a)** or with `transform`:

```
transform(df, date = `is.na<-`(date, date == "1900-01-01"))
```

**2)** We can use `if_na` in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(date = na_if(date, as.Date("1900-01-01")))
```